# This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http or https

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase and React Native to authenticate users into my app.

One thing I have noticed is when trying to use facebook login however I am thrown this error:

> This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http or https.

Not really sure how to solve it honestly

Comment: Which version of the Firebase JavaScript SDK are you using? For 3.x, React Native support was only added in [version 3.1](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.1.0).

Comment: hmm I installed it through npm so I figured it would be the latest one

Answer (score 12):

You must be using signInWithPopup/Redirect. This is only currently supported in a browser environment. You will need to use some native library (facebook/google) to retrieve the corresponding OAuth access token. Once you get that, you can call signInWithCredential to sign in the Firebase user:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(fbAccessToken))
```

Comment: Could you please tell me where i can get fbAccessToken is it may app secret key?