# How to use Firebase Authentication in Vue Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-native

I am using [Vue Native](https://vue-native.io/) with Firebase and try to make Firebase Auth work.
However, i can't.

I got this error message.

> this operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. location.protocol

I use Firebase Web SDK.

```
$ yarn add firebase
```

and I know what this error message means.

This application is native App and not running on http/https of course.

So what should I do to use Firebase with Vue Native?

Thanks in advance.

My code is here↓

```
<template>


<view class="container">
<button
  :on-press="signInWithGoogle"
  title="Sign In"
  color="#841584"
/>
</view>
</template>

<script>

import firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: "API-KEY",
  authDomain: "authDomain",
  databaseURL: "databaseURL",
  projectId: "projectId",
  storageBucket: "storageBucket",
  messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId"
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export default {
  methods: {
    signInWithGoogle() {
      firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Vue Native is a wrapper over React Native, so you may find some answers by mentioning react instead of vue, like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448800/this-operation-is-not-supported-in-the-environment-this-application-is-running-o or https://github.com/davideast/firebase-react-native-sample/issues/7

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase).

You can install using yarn

```
yarn add react-native-firebase
```

And start using their API as documented [here](https://rnfirebase.io/).

You should use --no-crna when init'ing your project.